# Return JQuery Value from a Drop Down

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down menus. One is state, the other is locations in the state. The second is loaded dynamically with JQuery.

I can not understand how to access the value of the selected from the second drop down so I can pass it to the next page.

search.php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"> <? echo $row['name'] ?></option>

<?php }
?>

<form method = "post" action="index.php?page=users">

                            <p>

                                <select name="list-select" id="list-select">
                                     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>

                                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                 </select>

                     <?php       

                    echo '<select name="list-target" id="list-target">';

                    echo '</select>';

                             $installation_id =  $_POST['list-target'];


                     mysqli_close($con);
                     ?>

                    </p>
                    <button type="input" name="submit" value="installations" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Check This Location</button>
                </form>
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#list-select").change(function() {
       $("#list-target").load("index.php?page=search&svalue=" + $("#list-select").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: what is this??? php, html, jquery all in one?

Comment: could you post the search page code?

Comment: what's in 'index.php?page=search&svalue='

Comment: Sorry was rushing. Broke out the code a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

"*how to access the value of the selected from the second drop down*"

I could identify this as your question so I think you need to find the value of selected option of the dropdown list..

```
 $("#list-select").change(function() {
     console.log($("#list-target option:selected").val());
 });
```

This will give you the value of selected option from the second dropdown (so that you can pass it into the URL, which is what you want).

Comment: Thanks yes that is my question. When I look at the log for this I the value doesn't even show the value of list-target. It shows list-select still, and shows the default for that. So I guess my question is two part. How do I get the value and then what do I do to get it back to my search.php so I can then pass it to my users.php page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'search') {
    $options = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo $options;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Try this

Comment: So I assume this goes at the top of my search page. I when I implement it the php page goes blank from this point forward. I assume there is an error but I can pick it out and not showing in console